# Django: How can I initialise a Charfield when using Add in an admin form?

Tags: django, django-admin, initialization

I have a Charfield 'status' [with choices = (('A', 'aaa'), ('B', 'bbb'), ('C', ccc'),)]

Can I initialise the field in the standard admin form to one of the choices?
A drop down appears but no choice is selected by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) option on the field?

```
CharField(default='A', choices=(...))
```

Comment: I have default option set in the model. I just tested it and it works. I think that, as usual, restarting the django server caused the fix to stick. Most excellent, JamesO.